# Better options for loading data into iframe with timeout loop

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I wasn't too sure on how to aptly title this question.

I would like to discuss the best way to POST/GET data with another website in a timely manner and using jQuery as the workhorse. Of course, I am open to suggestions with better methods and libraries albeit Javascript based or C#.

Let me try and set the scenario.

The two sites share the sub-domain 'a.company' but they are two separate IIS7 sites.

**Site 1**

- a.company.com/products
- ASP MVC 5
- Contains a 'puesdo' cart method to collect products wanted ready to pass to site2.

**Site 2**

- a.company.com/checkout
- pre-compiled by vendor no access to CS files, but can modify aspx / masterfile documents
- ASP Webforms
- Has limited API that will turn a URL into a product and add to it's cart.
- Example a.company.com/checkout/product/qty

Currently, when button 'proceed to checkout' is clicked on **site 1**, a jQuery function loops through each cart item and produces a url similar to: **a.company.com/checkout/product/qty** and then loads the URL into an iframe on the document. This loop has a setTimeout function also,

```
jQuery(function(){

  $('#proceed').on('click', function(){
       // set integer for timeout

       n = 2;

       $(cartobject).each(function(i){

              q = item.get('qty');
              p = item.get('productid');

              // delay loop
              setTimeout(function(){ 
                   ProceedItems(q,p) 
              }, 1000 * (i + 1));
              n = n + parseInt(i);
       });

       n = n * 2 + "000"; // from each function
       // delay redirect so loop can finish
       setTimeout(function(){
            RedirectCustomerToCheckout();
       }, n );


  });

  // Proceed each item to Checkout API
  function ProceedItems(quantity, productid)
  {
      $("#iframe").attr("src","http://a.company.com/checkout/" + productid + "/" + quantity);
  }

  // when loop as finished :: take customer to checkout process.
  function RedirectCustomerToCheckout()
  {
       window.location.href = "http://a.company.com/checkout";
  } 

});
```

This method is work, and i appreciate, the whole 'if it ain't broke' - but my anxiety is on edge the whole time as I think there must be a better way. perhaps adding code that checks that the iframe has completed it's loading / postback?

Main concerns are:
 - iframe not loading (and not generating any feedback)
 - page redirecting user without finishing loop (because of slow connection)?

Would using an Ajax POST/GET function with a reply success/failure/complete check be anymore secure in terms ensuring load completes.

Would really enjoy some suggestions.

```
Remote Address:10.0.0.100:800
Request URL:http://a.company.com/checkout/46026/1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found

GET /checkout/46026/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: a.company.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://a.company.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://a.company.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: You might find better help for this question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to get in a loop by this code?
n = n * 2 + "000";

Comment: Ensuring that the timeout of RedirectCustomerToCheckout is greater than the timeout of all the previous foreach instances.

Comment: The timeout value is going to increase incredibly fast: 2, 4000, 8000000, 16000000000 etc...

Comment: Thanks @Bart. ah i think thats a typo in my code. i will update soon..

Comment: Have you tried replacing the iFrame calls with ajax requests?

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna assume the `iframe` on your site is hidden and the user doesn't actually see it.
I would **definitely** use `ajax` instead of using an `iframe` for this.

This example will do all the requests in parallel ( up to 6 at a time in chrome ), and will then call `RedirectCustomerToCheckout` if they all completed successfully, or it will call `onFailedCheckout` if any of the requests fail or pass the default ajax timeout.

You can use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `$.get` if you want to use per request timeouts.

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#proceed').on('click', function () {
        var checkouts = [];
        $(cartobject).each(function (item) {
            var q = item.get('qty');
            var p = item.get('productid');
            checkouts.push($.get('http://a.company.com/checkout/' + p + '/' + q));
        });
        // $.when will wait for all checkouts to complete
        $.when.apply($, checkouts)
           .done(RedirectCustomerToCheckout)
           .fail(function onFailedCheckout() {
                alert('stuff broke !');
           });
    });

    // when loop as finished :: take customer to checkout process.
    function RedirectCustomerToCheckout() {
        window.location.href = 'http://a.company.com/checkout';
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi William, i was unsuccessful with this process. i can see the xhr being made by the a.company.com/checkout side is not fully receiving the request.

Comment: Could you post the headers from the xhr request and the iframe request ? If I could compare them I might be able to spot whats wrong

Comment: It would seem that it is hitting a 302 Not Found redirect. Which is by design of the API. It receives the request then redirects to the sites homepage. I have posted the header into the question..

Comment: @claw `302` actually means `Found` and should include a `location` header in the response that indicates what page to request next, but normally jquery should do this for you, could you add the response headers from the xhr request to your post as well please ?

Comment: @claw to Willem D'haeseleer's comment for the redirect check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location and How to correctly configure it on IIS7 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx. Hope it helps

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer I am still unable to get this working correctly.  The Ajax request fails based on the redirect.

Comment: @snowcode, post a new question with a code example and add the link here

Answer (score 1):

Since both share the same domain you can try something like this.

Here i am  making use of jQuery `.load` with callback.

instead of calling the iframe load in `.each`. i've used 'Q' Data Structure.

```
// our cartQ
var cartQ = new Array();


jQuery(function () {

    $('#proceed').on('click', function () {
        // re init the Q
        cartQ = new Array();
        // add each cartobject to Q
        $(cartobject).each(function (i) {
            cartQ.unshift(this);
        });

        // begin loading iframe.
        loadFromQ();
    });


    function loadFromQ() {
        if (cartQ.length !== 0) {
            var item = cartQ.pop();
            q = item.get('qty');
            p = item.get('productid');

            // pass same function as callback
            ProceedItems(q, p, loadFromQ);

        } else {
            RedirectCustomerToCheckout();
        }

    }
    // Proceed each item to Checkout API
    function ProceedItems(quantity, productid, callback) {
        $(document.body).append("<IFRAME id=p" + productid + " ...>");
        $('iframe#p' + productid).attr("http://a.company.com/checkout/" + productid + "/" + quantity, url);

        // call callback after loaded.
        $('iframe#p' + productid).load(function () {
            callback(this);
        });

    }

    // when loop as finished :: take customer to checkout process.
    function RedirectCustomerToCheckout() {
        window.location.href = "http://a.company.com/checkout";
    }

});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, I think you are doing presentation mainly on first web site and the checkout from another. in my opinion you should use jquery to add product template to user products, while firing jquery get (ajax) request to the product checkout url. all the calls to product checkout will add products to same cart and finally go to checkout will redirect the user to the users cart checkout page. i wont recommend using iframe unless you have a very specific reason for doing this.

Answer (score -1):

If all your doing is doing a get request on a url, then why not just append an image to your page with url and the query-string as the img src

```
<img src="http://...your endpoint url?querystring..." class="hidden" >
```

You can use the img onload event to get a confirmation that the server sent a response, that will give you the functionality to use an async loop that is re-called on the onload event and when all items are sent redirects the user to the checkout.

Or you can just append as many images to the page as items in the cart, listen for the onload events on all and when all have loaded redirect.

Comment: -1 using images as a makeshift GET only REST Interface seems like a horrible, horrible idea. That's going to confuse the crap out of any following developers, besides that the iframe also has an onload event so I would even prefer that over this. In any event AJAX is the only right solution here, unless there is some valid reason why the OP can't make it work.

Comment: I completely agree with you, the sensible way of sending requests to a server is an xhr request, my suggestion was meant as another way of sending a request. Sometimes the obvious is not always the obvious. If the server is on the same domain, xhr is the way to go. It was meant as just another way of doing it, by no means the way to do.

Comment: I suppose my attempt at offering something different should of been a script tag with a url in it, that said I'm sure you would find that a horrible horrible idea too. -1 to Google analytic's JavaScript client api.

Comment: Google analytics uses an images because it predates CORS by far and they want to support really old browsers. The OP site is on the same server so there really is no need for an image here.

Comment: Correct. Which is a horrible horrible way for Google to send millions and millions and trillions of bytes of data to their servers. On just about every webpage, I bet it's even on yours. Horrible!

Comment: Just so we are not confused. Xhr is the way to go. +1